# How do I match the content in double quotes with regexp in golang?

Tags: json, regex, go

```
content := `{null,"Age":24,"Balance":33.23}`
rule,_ := regexp.Compile(`"([^\"]+)"`)
results := rule.FindAllString(content,-1)
fmt.Println(results[0]) //"Age" 
fmt.Println(results[1]) //"Balance"
```

There is a json string with a ``null`` value that it look like this.

This json is from a web api and i don't want to replace anything inside.

I want to using regex to match all the keys in this json which are without the double quote and the output are ``Age`` and ``Balance`` but not ``"Age"`` and ``"Balance"``.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Parsing JSON is best done without regex. In golang you can use json unmarshal, then use them as an object as normal.

Comment: That's not JSON. If you want to capture the quotes, put the quotes into the capture group (i.e. inside the parentheses).

Comment: @Ajaypayne It is not a standard json, I have to deal with unqualified attributes before I can get the json object.

Comment: @YuliangLi That only poses a problem if you want to unmarshal into a struct. You could unmarshal to a map for example (from decode.go infile comments on unmarshal - 
// To unmarshal a JSON object into a map, Unmarshal first establishes a map to
// use. If the map is nil, Unmarshal allocates a new map. Otherwise Unmarshal
// reuses the existing map, keeping existing entries. Unmarshal then stores
// key-value pairs from the JSON object into the map. The map's key type must
// either be a string, an integer, or implement encoding.TextUnmarshaler.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to use a regular expression that matches any character between quotes (such as your example or `".*?"`) and either put a matching group (aka "submatch") inside the quotes or return the relevant substring of the match, using [`regexp.FindAllStringSubmatch(...)`](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.FindAllStringSubmatch) or [`regexp.FindAllString(...)`](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.FindAllString), respectively.

For example ([Go Playground](https://play.golang.com/p/ICO9g1hsTTK)):

```
func main() {
  str := `{null,"Age":24,"Balance":33.23}`

  fmt.Printf("OK1: %#v\n", getQuotedStrings1(str))
  // OK1: []string{"Age", "Balance"}
  fmt.Printf("OK2: %#v\n", getQuotedStrings2(str))
  // OK2: []string{"Age", "Balance"}
}

var re1 = regexp.MustCompile(`"(.*?)"`) // Note the matching group (submatch).

func getQuotedStrings1(s string) []string {
  ms := re1.FindAllStringSubmatch(s, -1)
  ss := make([]string, len(ms))
  for i, m := range ms {
    ss[i] = m[1]
  }
  return ss
}

var re2 = regexp.MustCompile(`".*?"`)

func getQuotedStrings2(s string) []string {
  ms := re2.FindAllString(s, -1)
  ss := make([]string, len(ms))
  for i, m := range ms {
    ss[i] = m[1 : len(m)-1] // Note the substring of the match.
  }
  return ss

}
```

Note that the second version (without a submatching group) may be slightly faster based on a simple benchmark, if performance is critical.